# Why doesn't my break work?

Tags: c#, while-loop, break

I am programming in C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
Somewhere in my code, I'm using break keyword in a while loop after checking if the line's value is null or not.

I am sure that line value is null but still the break command doesn't work.
How can I fix this?

```
while (!myfile.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = myfile.ReadLine();

    if (line == null) { break; }
    else
    { ...}
}
```

Comment: If it's not the end of the stream then will the line ever be null? It might be an empty string but I don't think it can be null

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: For future reference, it's not that you break doesn't work, it's that the code never reaches that point (because line is never null). Sticking a breakpoint on the `break` would have made that obvious.

Comment: the line value becomes null at the end of stream and I checked for that too, I mean I checked if you reached end of stream then break but that doesn't work too.

Comment: I am sure the null value is null

Comment: Also, I've always like `while ((line = myfile.ReadLine())!=null)` which both populates `line` and quits when there are no more lines.

Comment: Try toi write to console more often to really see whats going on. Or make statements and codebreaks to help you debug things like this.

Comment: `line` is never null, or it *would* break. Use the debugger and add a watch on `line`. Or put the `break` statement on a separate line and put a breakpoint on it. It won't hit it.

Comment: Also, check the [docs for StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that the only time it returns `null` is when it's at the end of the stream, but you already checked if it's at the end of the stream with your `while` condition. Therefore, `line` can *never* be null with the code as your written it.

Answer (score 7):

Its not null, you are getting either an empty string back or string with White Space (Line breaks etc). 
Its better if you modify your check as :

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) { break; } //checks null and white space 
                                                // or empty string
```

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is provided with .Net framework 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Which is okay so long as there aren't any expected blank lines in your file!

Answer (score 1):

The null check is not needed.  It is already being enforced by the `EndOfStream` check.  It can be removed.